# @Path not responding for basic @GET request in Java servlet in Eclipse Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat9

[image]I'm new to Eclipse and Apache Tomcat and am trying to complete a basic get request. I successfully installed Apache Tomcat and started the server, but when I go to the configured route I receive a 404 error. From my understanding, I have the class and the web.xml file configured properly. How can I successfully complete a get request in Eclipse and return the expected resource?

The class I have configured with the path and get annotation is in a default (unnamed packaged) and is below:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/attempt")
public class TestAttempt {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {     
        System.out.println("not working");      
        return "Got it!";
    }       
}
```

And my web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
  <display-name>Test3</display-name>

 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>TestAttempt</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I then go to localhost:8080/test/attempt and receive the 404 instead of the expected: "Got it!"

Comment: is you code actually deployed? check below `tomcat/webapps`

Comment: i'm running it locally

Comment: I understand that you are running Tomcat within Eclipse, but it still gets deployed.

Comment: where is that? i only have a WebContent file

Comment: i added a pic of my Eclipse setup if that helps at all.

Comment: read https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/where-is-eclipse-deploy-web-application-tomcat/

Comment: i don't think that's the issue since i was able to hit a jsp file. i just can't return a resource from a get request.

Answer (score 1):

Your class TestAttempt is not a servlet as it doesn't extend HttpServlet. Can you make this change and try again.

Comment: it's still giving me a 404 even after extending HttpServlet

Answer (score 0):

Check servlet-mapping of your servlet in web.xml and be sure that your web url like http://localhost:8080/test/attempt

Comment: i've tried that numerous times. you can see the web.xml file above. doGet requests work, just not the path configured with the Get and Path annotations